# customizations in django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I am working on a django project and using django 1.9. I want to customize the django-admin such that I can search from the list of vegetables in the model "Vegetable". The snapshot is attached below. [image]

I want to have a search bar in the django-admin from which the user can search for any vegetable. I want to know is there any backend way to do this. I know django-admin customisation may be done in javascript but I am looking for a more back end approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[search_fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.search_fields) can be used for this.